# Is this possible to create an exclusive volume for each replicated container with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, replication, docker-volume

I was trying to start multiple Elasticsearch containers with docker compose. something like this:

```yaml
  elasticsearch-cluster-data-node:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:latest
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
    environment:
      - node.name=esdata
      - node.roles=data,ingest
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
```

However, I ended up with this error:

```
failed to obtain node locks, tried [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data];
maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started on the same data path?
```

So I want to know if there is any solution to provide particular volume for each container replica.

Comment: That is not possible; see discussions [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43079) and [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9026).